# Questions regarding TV commercials

Tags: discussion, faq, scope, asking-questions

Would it be okay to ask questions regarding TV commercials here? For example,

- In what country [this] commercial was produced?
- What is the background song title used in [this] commercial?
- What is the x person doing in [this] commercial?
- Production methods applied to commercials, and how they differ from those used in TV programs or movies
- Practices employed in television advertising (e.g. why I sometimes see the same ad twice in a row)
- Particular advertising campaigns (e.g. why there are so many car commercials on American television)
- How ads affect the structure of TV programs (how ad slots are allocated)
  Or any others that come to mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any particular reason why a question about the production, or analysis of a commercial would not be on topic.  That said, I personally do not think you are going to get a lot of interest in questions about commercials, and may attract both down and close votes.

Addressing the specific examples, its generally considered just trivia to ask about the songs/music in movies and tv - and we are not a music site.  If the music in some way is particularly important to the commercial, then this starts to become analysis.  Questions just asking to identify a song are generally closed.

The 'what country' / 'what is the x person doing' questions could be viewed as just trivia - but that depends on the question.

Comment: Yeah, i'm just ot sure if there will be a lot of interest in these questions.

Comment: Not only trivia, but some questions might be considered *Too Localized*.

Comment: Also note that the question `What is the background song title used in [this] commercial?` is now off-topic for different reasons.