# How to address the "Advertising" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Many of the 15 questions (of which two are closed) tagged [advertising](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising) are actually about [product-placement](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-placement) or [marketing](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing).

In relation to the former, I feel that product placement is the preferable tag because of its specific relationship to Movies & TV. Advertising is a huge world that includes many things, most of which do not relate to our topic.

Here are the questions that currently have the advertising tag (ignoring the closed questions) and what I propose be done to them:

These should be [product-placement](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-placement) only.  They are currently either tagged both [advertising](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising) **and** [product-placement](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-placement) or [advertising](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising) only:

- [Are weapon manufacturer investing in product placement?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/32658/are-weapon-manufacturer-investing-in-product-placement) [sic]
- [Are the brands worn by the stars in a movie part of promotions?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31325/are-the-brands-worn-by-the-stars-in-a-movie-part-of-promotions)
- [Is every appearance of a product in a movie sponsored?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/23540/is-every-appearance-of-a-product-in-a-movie-sponsored)
- [Why is a special company's product shown through out a film?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/6876/why-is-a-special-companys-product-shown-through-out-a-film)
- [First movie with product placement?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/first-movie-with-product-placement)

These are actually about [marketing](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing) and should have the [advertising](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising) tag replaced:

- [Why are American movies often promoted abroad with titles -in English- that are different from the originals? [duplicate]](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17477/why-are-american-movies-often-promoted-abroad-with-titles-in-english-that-are) (this is probably actually fine with **only** the [title](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title) tag... the [translation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) tag is silly because there's no actual translation happening, just rewording... but it's a duplicate, so it probably doesn't matter anyway)
- [What is the main promotional image of House of Cards trying to portray?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10126/what-is-the-main-promotional-image-of-house-of-cards-trying-to-portray)
- [First movie that collaborated with fast-food outlets?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2164/first-movie-that-collaborated-with-fast-food-outlets) (Media tie-ins are [cross-promotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-promotion), a form of marketing)

This is just a general question about Big Bang Theory and I don't really think it needs an additional tag:

- [Why doesn't the restaurant resemble an actual Cheesecake Factory?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11511/why-doesnt-the-restaurant-resemble-an-actual-cheesecake-factory)

Should just be tagged [reality-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-tv)... this question is not about advertising at all... and, yes, I get that you shouldn't correct tags based on answers but the premise of the question is flawed and rules/laws that relate to advertising do not relate to entertainment TV:

- [How are fake reality shows not false advertising? And if they are, why do they get away with it?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/24229/how-are-fake-reality-shows-not-false-advertising-and-if-they-are-why-do-they-g)

These are questions about commercials, not necessarily about films or TV shows (though some are tangentially related). Commercials seem to be [on-topic](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/740/questions-regarding-tv-commercials?s=1%7C0.8214) here and [advertising](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising) (or advertisement?) could certainly be an option to separate these questions... or just [commercial](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commercial)... though this goes against the concept of not having "movie" or "TV" tags because that's what the site is about.

- [Are Movie Stars typically forbidden from appearing in future commercials resembling a played character?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31313/are-movie-stars-typically-forbidden-from-appearing-in-future-commercials-resembl) This one probably has more tags than it needs...
- [Can someone explain the Acura “I sell cars, you sell you” ads?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/30129/can-someone-explain-the-acura-i-sell-cars-you-sell-you-ads) ([seinfeld](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seinfeld) needs to be removed, could have [plot-explanation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plot-explanation)?)
- [Identify an Actress in Impluse Body Spray commercial from early 2000s](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/19718/identify-an-actress-in-impluse-body-spray-commercial-from-early-2000s) (probably fine with just the identify tag)

This last group is the one I feel needs the most discussion but thoughts regarding all of the above are welcome.

Comment: Nice proposal and reasoning. However, how does a `commercial` tag go *"against the concept of not having "movie" or "TV" tags"*? Afterall, *if* commercials are on-topic, then I guess a `commercial` is just a specific "genre" of movies/TV-shows. While not saying I'm completely in favour of it, I don't see a `commercial` tag conflicting with the policy of `movie` and `tv` tags being useless, seems a completely unrelated problem. And it's not that even 1% of the questions here would have that tag, let alone half of 'em.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson You are probably right... I'm just trying to be cautious. Personally, I don't mind the idea of tagging questions about commercials as such but I don't necessarily want to encourage questions about them, even if they are on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like this idea a lot and it would clean up the advertising/marketing tags - I wouldn't worry about the translation tag as I think that's one of the ones that will end up being retired at some point. Just going through the questions you've linked in your post - in order:

- First five regarding [product-placement](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-placement) - I agree, we should remove [advertising](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising) from these
- Next three regarding [marketing](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing) - I agree - [marketing](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing) is probably the right tag
- The TBBT question - it's not actually about advertising, since the Cheesecake factory have no arrangement with the studio. Just the [the-big-bang-theory](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-big-bang-theory) tag should be sufficient
- The reality TV question - I agree, just tag it [reality-tv](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-tv)

Regarding the last three - I agree with not having a [commercial](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commercial) tag, these are actually (according to the scope, anyway) on topic and if we actually get genuine questions on the topic we would probably need to revisit how these are tagged - since during the life of the site to date there hasn't been a genuine question that needed a specific tag we don't need to have one right now.

The "are movie stars forbidden" question is a [legal](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) question. I'm not even sure it should be tagged [copyright](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright). It's about characters so [character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) is good but it's not about [casting](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/casting). I'd go with [character](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character) [legal](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal).

The second question regarding comedians in cars probably needs a tag (maybe [comedians-in-cars](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comedians-in-cars) since [comedians-in-cars-getting-coffee](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comedians-in-cars-getting-coffee) is too long). The existing tags should be removed.

The identification question should only have the relevant identification tag against it.

Comment: The comedians in cars question isn't actually about the show, though... is it? It's just about ads that happen to be run with the show? I don't know anything about it, so I'm not sure what the deal is.

Comment: I don't know, I had a quick look and it looks like the ads were [written by Jerry Seinfeld for the show](http://www.adweek.com/adfreak/qa-how-jerry-seinfeld-wrote-his-ideal-salesman-acuras-new-ads-158686).