# Cameras and cinematography

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Following on from [my initial post](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1733/5603) and [the subsequent discussion on cleaning up the advertising tag](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1740/5603), would it be possible for us to discuss [camera](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera) and [cinematography](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinematography)?

[camera](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera)

> Questions about the use of cameras and camera-related film techniques.

[cinematography](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinematography)

> Cinematography is the art or science of motion picture photography.

Both of these tags are used for the same sort of question, if you look through what we've currently got tagged on each. This should be doable with nothing more than merging one tag into the other. I'd prefer to keep [cinematography](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinematography) and merge [camera](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera) into it but I don't really mind either way.

What do you think?

Comment: I agree - I think that cinematography is the broader subject, and we're not a technical 'camera' site anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Merging those two is very good idea, they've always been a thorn in my eye. They seem to be synonyms for all intents and purposes.

One could argue that [cinematography](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinematography) is more about the action of filming and operating cameras, while [camera](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera) is more specifically about the actual technological things. But I agree with *iandotkelly*'s comment that *"we're not a technical 'camera' site"*. And when looking at the existing questions, nearly all of the [camera](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera) questions also would fall into the action of [cinematography](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinematography) and the very few more technical things are probably also well-covered by the broader topic of cinematography.

I would thus agree that we merge them, and specifically **merge [camera](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/camera) into [cinematography](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinematography) (and probably make it a synonym)**.

Comment: Merge *and* synonym. In the short term the synonym eases the transition for existing users, cinematography can be a bit of a mouthful for a non-native english speaker and if it gets in the way in the long term we can just remove it

Comment: "Merge *and* synonym" - Sure, of course merging and synonymizing doesn't come exclusively. A synonym should always be merged anyway.

Comment: sounds good to me

Comment: I agree, and think they should be synonyms.